# Formatting of number with currency symbol

Tags: excel

I am values in Excel with format (e.g. ₹18.05 with custom format as [$₹-ur-IN]#,##0.00. There are times when the values are displayed as ₹0.00. In the cases the value happen to be ₹0.00, I want to display blank cell. Please let me know what changes are required in custom format to achieve the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The format is specified as

```
<Format for positive values>;<Format for negative values>;<Format for zero values>
```

You can just provide no format for the case where you have a zero:

```
[$₹-1FAE37]#,##0.00;-[$₹-1FAE37]#,##0.00;
```

depending how you want to handle any negative values.

Semicolon (;) may be a different character in your locale.

[image]